# Can I use the connection from Entity Framework or should I create a new one?

Tags: database, entity-framework, sqlite, database-connection, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLite Database that I access using [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org). The database is read into my Entity Framework Objectcontext. However, I also need direct access to the database in certain cases.

1. Can I / Should I use the same connection that my Entity Framework object context is using? I.e. `ObjectContext.Connection`?
2. If yes, how can I access it? Casting `Entities.Connection` to `SQLiteConnection` results in *"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection' to type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'."*
3. If not, should I create a seperate connection, open it and keep it open for the application duration, or should I open and close the connection every time I want to access the database with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectContext.Connection` is an `EntityConnection`. You can get the store connection via:

```
var sc = ((EntityConnection)ObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;
```

You can cast that to the `SQLiteConnection`.

It's OK to use this connection if you need it.

But, as @Chris mentioned, you can just use `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery`, etc., if that will do for you.

Comment: I ended up using `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` which worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: LOL I just ended up reading this question and using the answer, without realising it was me who originally posted it! Craig, if I could mark it twice, I would!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the DBContext API you can actually execute a direct query by using this: aDBContext.Database.SqlQuery

I wouldn't be surprised if something similar exists for the ObjectContext API, but I barely used that one and thus can't tell you what it is.

Now if for some reason you can't (or don't want) to do that, I'd create a new connection for your custom queries. Put them in a Using and close it as soon as you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Entity Framework` has built in methods for executing raw SQL queries if that's what you need to do.