# Fetch rows from database using ExecuteStoreQuery, without knowing the number of columns in the table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, executestorequery

I'm trying to do some manual SQL queries against my SQLite database using the `ExecuteStoreQuery` method on my `ObjectContext`.

The catch is that I don't always know how many columns are in the table that I'm querying. Ideally, I would like each fetched row to simply be an `string[]` object.

I've looked at Example 2 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd487208(v=vs.100).aspx

It's close to what I want to do, except that I don't know the structure of the `TElement` I'm fetching, so I can't define a struct as they do in the example.

Below is some of my code (not compiling due to the `????` `TElement`). The code below is trying to fetch the table info, so in this case I do know the structure of the rows, but in general I don't.

Is there a way to do this with `ExecuteStoreQuery`? Or is there a different way of doing it, while still using the existing connection of my `ObjectContext` (rather than opening a new SQL connection to the DB)?

```
public void PrintColumnHeaders(NWRevalDatabaseEntities entities, string tableName)
{
    string columnListQuery = string.Format("PRAGMA table_info({0})", tableName);

    var result = entities.ExecuteStoreQuery<????>(columnListQuery);

    foreach (string[] row in result)
    {
        string columnHeader = row[1]; // Column header is in second column of table
        Console.WriteLine("Column Header: {0}", columnHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this call for a lower level approach: issue a command against the store connection (returning `object[]`).

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, I got this working thanks to you. Would you like to post as answer so I can accept?

Comment: You did all the work! I suggest you move your UPDATE to an answer and mark it.

Comment: You're too kind :-) I'll accept tomorrow after the unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working based on Gert Arnold's comment. Also, it took me some effort to figure out that I need a SQLiteConnection, not the EntityConnection that I could get directly from the ObjectContext. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830410/can-i-use-the-connection-from-entity-framework-or-should-i-create-a-new-one) question helped me with that.

The working code is below:

```
public static void PrintColumnHeaders(NWRevalDatabaseEntities entities, string tableName)
{
    var sc = ((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)entities.Connection).StoreConnection;
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection sqliteConnection = (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection)sc;

    sqliteConnection.Open();
    System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = sc.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("PRAGMA table_info('{0}');", tableName);
    System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int result = reader.GetValues(values);
            string columnHeader = (string)values[1]; // table_info returns a row for each column, with the column header in the second column.
            Console.WriteLine("Column Header: {0}", columnHeader);
        }
    }
    sqliteConnection.Close();
}
```